# Callback sharing data in Matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, callback

I have being to share data between several callback options in Matlab, however no succes so far. I have a gui with multiple tables which I use to get the input from the user. I have multiple callback functions for the different tables. I would like to use the data from table 1 and callback 1 together with the date in table 2 in callback two.

```
function MaterialProperties(Material, Data)
Material_data = get(Material, 'Data');
% Avoid bluehighlight in table
set(Material,'Data',{'dummy'});
set(Material,'Data', Material_data);    
% Store variable in workspace
assignin('base','Material_data',Material_data)
%Mat_data = guidata(gcbo);
%for i=1:size(Material_data,2)
%    Mat_data.MatData{i}=Material_data{i};
%end
% Save the change you made to the structure
guidata(gcbo,Mat_data) 
assignin('base','Mat_data',Mat_data)
end

function Stacking_sequence(Layup, Data)
% I want to use the date (Material_data) of MaterialProperties here in this callback 

layup_data = get(Layup, 'Data');
%overwrite data with a dummy and restore the old data afterwards, to force deselection
set(Layup,'Data',{'dummy'});
set(Layup,'Data', layup_data );
%store variable in workspace
assignin('base','layup_data',layup_data) 

layup =  strsplit(layup_data{1,1},'\');
assignin('base','layup',layup)

end
```

Can anyone help. I tried theMatlab help, but the suggestions stated there didn't work (maybe I implemented it wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you simply need to retrieve the handles structure at the beginning of  callback 2, like you did in the first callback:

```
Mat_data = guidata(gcbo);
```

after which it should be available in the 2nd callback. By the way this very line and the 3 lines following it are commented in your code is that a mistake?

**Alternative solution:**

As an alternative solution, you can use setappdata/getappdata to share data between function callbacks as well as in the command window, depending on where you store those data.

For example, if you save `Material_data` at the end of the 1st callback using something like this:

```
setappdata(0,'MatData',Material_Data); % Save in the Matlab root 0 (accessible everywhere), and give some dummy name)
```

Then at the beginning of the 2nd callback, you can retrieve the data using getappdata:

```
Material_Data = getappdata(0,'MatData');
```

and you're good to go. Instead of using the 0 root, you could also store the data in the GUI itself, using for example handles.FigureGUI or whatever the name of the figure is. Then the data would be available only if the figure is not closed/deleted. Play around with those and see what you prefer.

Hope that helps!

Comment: However, one more quick question. If I change the handle gcbo  to e.g. bla, I get an error saying undefined variable 'bla'. How can I change the handles. Thanks!

Comment: Did you make the GUI with GUIDE? If so, the name (tag) of the figure is by default figure1, and its handle is handles.figure1. You can change it directly in GUIDE using the property inspector.

Comment: No, I coded the tables (I have no figures). But if I add 'Tag', 'Name', and use that Name I still get an error. I also tried handles.Name, but no luck there.

Comment: ok. Maybe you can assign a handle to the table during its creation and use it, like hTable = uitable(...) ?

Comment: I also tried that, but that didn't work. Got the same error: Undefined function or variable 'hTable'.